# rename file and save old and new name to output file

Tags: linux, bash, csv

Im using

```
for i in *.jpg; do mv $i $(openssl rand -rand $i -hex 16).jpg; done
```

to rename files in a directory.

What I need to do is keep track of the name change from old name to new. So I would like to output a text or csv file

Example output csv or txt file:

```
old_name, new_name
1234.jpg, 0dd4e436bd9482e8e679fa471aaf9b0e.jpg
```

adding the typical

```
>>output_file
```

or

```
| tee
```

is not working for me in this for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "old_name, new_name" > output_file.csv
for old in *.jpg; do 
  new=$(openssl rand -rand "$old" -hex 16).jpg
  echo "$old, $new" >> output_file.csv
  mv "$old" "$new"
done
```